# In react setInterval and again setInterval. I want to check if user is active on the page or not

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io, timeout, setinterval

I want to setInterval again and again in react. I want to check if user is active on the page or not. if he is typing then I can make him active and if not then I can close the connection.

https://devforhelp.com/chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use setTimeOut() for check user typing.

```
useEffect(() => {
    let timeout;

    refInput.current.addEventListener('keypress', () => { /* user is typing */
        if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
        userIsActive();

        timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            userIsNotActive();
        }, 30000 /* 30 second */);
    });
}, []);
```

Comment: Hi, it is not for showing whether user is typing or not, that was just an example.

Comment: I want to know if user is active on the chatting app or not and the above code is not working as I want. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: For accurate results, you must use sockets.
But there are other ways to detect that the user is active. For example, using Ajax.
Exactly which technology (Socket or ...) do you mean?

Comment: Im using socket.io and I want to close idle connections https://devforhelp.com/chat

Comment: Your question was that you want to close the user's connection when he is not typing.
Well, you can put the commands related to closing the connection inside the userIsNotActive() function.
where is the problem ?